# Bundler - could not find compatible versions for gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, hudson, bundler

I try to install Husdon 1.0.8.1 for my BitNami Redmine 2.0.3 (Windows 7)

```
rake redmine:migrate:plugins
```

Result:

```
Bundler could not find compatible versions for gem "builder":
  In Gemfile:
    cucumber (= 0.9.4) x86-mingw32 depends on
      builder (~> 2.1.2) x86-mingw32

    builder (3.0.0)
```

My gemlist is ok:

```
builder (3.0.0, 2.1.2)
cucumber (0.9.4)
```

... and many more ;)

Answer (score 4):

What bundler does is it tries to match up all the dependencies of all gems in the gemfile.

This includes **matching the versions of all gems** with the requirements.

You have a mix of version requirements which are impossible for bundler to fulfill:

```
builder (~> 2.1.2) x86-mingw32
```

...means match version > 2.1.2, but < 2.2.0 (very strict requirement).

```
builder (3.0.0)
```

...means match only 3.0.0 (even stricter).

So you see you can't match both 2.1.2-2.2.0 and 3.0.0 at the same time. You need to loosen up your requirements or change the version numbers so that the requirements can be matched.